# Get value from iput HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, getelementbyid

I have the following html code:

```
<form name="Register" action="Register.aspx" method="post" runat="server" style="margin-top: 15px;" onsubmit="return validateProfile(FormName='Register');" >
 <p>
 Name* : <input id="FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName"/> </p>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And this JS code:

```
function isEmpty(field) {
    return (field == "" || field == null)
}

function validateProfile(FormName) {
    var Fname = document.forms[FormName]["FirstName"].value; return false;
    var g = (isEmpty(field));
    alert(g);

}
```

The problem is in this line :

> var Fname = document.forms[FormName]["FirstName"].value; return
>   false;

I get this error message :

> uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined

If I write instead of the line above this line

`document.getElementById("FirstName").value`

It works great, so my question is why `document.forms[FormName]["FirstName"].value` does not work?

Comment: it seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/PmFX9/. make sure you are passing valid form name in function

Comment: Yep, check the value of `FormName`. `alert(FormName)` or `console.log(FormName)`. It seems to be wrong or unset

Answer (score 2):

`document.forms[FormName]["FirstName"]` will try to access a property on a javascript HTMLFormElement forms object. The [Id] syntax can only be used on a collection. To access an element with the id FirstName use `document.forms[FormName].elements['FirstName'].value`

Answer (score 1):

`document.forms[name]` returns the element, not a mapping input name => value. This would work :

```
var Fname = document.forms[FormName].getElementsByTagName('Input')[5].value;
return false;
```

Comment: @NaveTseva: "Doesn't work" is not an error message.  :P  Showing the new error message, or mentioning that you're still getting the same error, would help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I wasn't copy the code correctly, it works great! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your validation function has some problem

I don't know why you are using

```
        return false;
```

after

```
     var Fname = document.forms[FormName]["FirstName"].value;
```

Try this

```
    function validateProfile(FormName) {
        var Fname = document.forms[FormName]["FirstName"].value; 
        var g = (isEmpty(Fname));
        alert(g);

    }
```

I don't know what problem you are facing exactly so I am attaching the complete working cope of the code and tested on chrome and IE as below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <form name="Register" action="Register.aspx" method="post" runat="server" style="margin-top: 15px;" onsubmit="return validateProfile('Register');" >
     <p>
     Name* : <input id="FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName"/> </p>
     <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <script language="javascript">


    document.write(document.forms[0].name);

    function isEmpty(field) {
        return (field == "" || field == null)
    }

    function validateProfile(formname) {
        var Fname = document.forms[formname]["FirstName"].value; 
        var g = (isEmpty(Fname ));
        alert(g);
    return false;

    }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: added the complete working code. Plz mention the specific error if still doesn't work.